# Bash - Read only the last 100 lines of a long Log file

Tags: bash, variables, while-loop

I am reading a long log file and splitting the columns in variables using bash.

```
cd $LOGDIR
IFS="," 
while read LogTIME name md5 
do
    LogTime+="$(echo $LogTIME)"
    Name+="$(echo $name)"
    LOGDatamd5+="$(echo $md5)"
done < LOG.txt
```

But this is really slow and I don't need all the lines. The last 100 lines are enough (but the log file itself needs all the other lines for different programs).

I tried to use `tail -n 10 LOG.txt | while read LogTIME name md5`, but that takes really long as well and I had no output at all.
Another way I tested without success was:

```
cd $LOGDIR
foo="$(tail -n 10 LOG.txt)"
IFS="," 
while read LogTIME name md5 
do
    LogTime+="$(echo $LogTIME)"
    Name+="$(echo $name)"
    LOGDatamd5+="$(echo $md5)"
done < "$foo"
```

But that gives me only the output of foo in total. Nothing was written into the variables inside the while loop.

There is probably a really easy way to do this, that I can't see...

Cheers,
BallerNacken

Comment: why you do tail -10 when you need 100?

Comment: That was just for test purposes and I forgot to change it. Has no impact on the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Process substitution is the common pattern:

```
while read LogTIME name md5 ; do
    LogTime+=$LogTIME
    Name+=$name
    LogDatamd5+=$md5
done < <(tail -n100 LOG.txt)
```

Note that you don't need `"$(echo $var)"`, you can assign `$var` directly.